# QGIS zonal statistics of raster as virtual field for each polygon in vector layer

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, field-calculator, zonal-statistics

I have a vector layer containing multiple polygons. Also I have raster layer.
Now I would like to add  virtual fields (via field calculator) to the attribute table containing the mean/max/min value of the raster values for each polygon.

I know zonal statistics can achieve this calculation, however it returns a separate layer. I prefer to add a virtual field to the attribute table, as I have to repeat this step often for other layers and can thus easily copy/pasting all virtual field definitions using the style-copying function.

Comment: Sounds like you will likely need to use PyQGIS. What have you tried and where do you get stuck?

Comment: I never used PyQGis so far. Can you hint me where to start for this problem?